# singleTask activity not loading properly

Tags: android, android-activity

I have an activity 'A' defined in Manifest like below:

```
<activity
    android:name=".A"
    android:launchMode="singleTask"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait">

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>

</activity>
```

When I launch my APP,  that activity is always loaded from the start. It wont start from my prev activity.
When I remove `android:launchMode`, then it works as I expect.

Comment: <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" /> means that the current activity is the started point of your application.

Answer (score 2):

Since you set `android:launchMode="singleTask"`, the activity A will always be the root of your activities.

From [DOCS](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode):

> In contrast, "singleTask" and "singleInstance" activities can only begin a task. They are always at the root of the activity stack. Moreover, the device can hold only one instance of the activity at a time — only one such task.

Default mode is `standard`. So, when you remove `android:launchMode="singleTask"`, your APP returns to `standard` launch mode.

That's why if you app is always starting Activity A.

Comment: for deeplick should i cr8 empty activity?

Comment: @andro you should also put the `category.DEFAULT` in the intent filter if you want it to work correctly and not `LAUNCHER`

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to start a different Activity on launch replace that in the xml name attribute that contains **LAUNCHER**

```
<activity
    android:name=".ActivityB"
    android:launchMode="singleTask"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
  >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>

</activity>
```

Where Activity B is an alternate activity.

Comment: i want a to be open but when my app is in memory and i click on app icon it should start from act where it was not from a activity